# What, if any, are the dangers of passing serialized data through a diagnostic?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Creating a diagnostic allows you to pass in a `Dictionary<string, string>` with self-defined data. Afterwards you can use this in whatever reads the diagnostic to provide contextual information. A typical scenario this is available in is between an analyzer and a code fix.

How reliable is this method of passing data? Are there any special considerations that should be kept in mind?

I recall a discussion on the subject months ago when the concern about serializability was brought up as a reason not to provide such a feature. Something else that comes to mind is the possibility of race conditions (code fixes acting upon outdated information from the analyzer) but I'm questioning how likely this is (or whether it's even possible). A diagnostic should be cancelled when the syntax tree is changed though I'm not aware if this propagates to the Code Fix.

To give [a specific example](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/pull/353/files): I'm doing some tricks to discover two things: a parameter name and a location. In the analyzer this location is used to display the squiggly underlining while the parameter is used to create a new invocation.
Rather than computing the parameter name and the location twice, I pass both through the `properties` argument and then retrieve the affected node from the code fix using that location as determined in the analyzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the properties will be maintained as long as the diagnostic exist in the system. so you can rely on data you have put in from analyzer.

but that being said, if it is possible, avoiding using the property bag will be better for users.

these pre-computed diagnostics are generated without user interactions and saved in the system for whole solution, so those little extra information per diagnostic do add up. (basically consume resources)

compared to diagnostic, fixer will only run when there is an explicit user action and only run small number of fixers (usually ones applicable for a line where caret is on)

so putting some data in diagnostic just to make fixer little bit faster (if speed up is significant, then you might have your justification) is like loading control panel on every system reboot to speed up first launch time in case you MIGHT use control panel before shutdown the machine.